# Is there a JMX Command Line Interface for querying MBEAN attributes that works with Java 1.4.2?

Tags: command-line-interface, jmx

There a number of CLIs such as Jmxterm but they require Java 1.5.

We have some old systems running Java 1.4.2 that we need to query via JMX.

I'm not even sure that JMX at that stage is capable of providing MBEAN attributes.

If you know of a 1.4.2 compatible CLI you will make my day!

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Why not activate remote JMX connections and connect to your Java 1.4 program from a machine running Java 1.5+ and using those tools?